# How to find the most common part of a string?

Tags: java, string

Let's say we have a collection of strings.

```
asList("abcdxyz", "abcdyz", "abcdm", "abcdn", "abcdo");
```

How we can find the most common part "abcd" using the String class methods only?

Comment: Can the common part occur anywhere or just the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Longest Common Substring](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring) problem(for n strings).

You may use this code for a start but the code might crawl for large values of 'n'. In that case, you should better use dynamic programming[see the relevant section [here]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

```
public static String identifyCommonSubStrOfNStr(String [] strArr){

    String commonStr="";
    String smallStr ="";        

    //identify smallest String      
    for (String s :strArr) {
        if(smallStr.length()< s.length()){
            smallStr=s;
        }
    }

    String tempCom="";
    char [] smallStrChars=smallStr.toCharArray();               
    for (char c: smallStrChars){
        tempCom+= c;

        for (String s :strArr){
            if(! s.contains(tempCom)){
            tempCom="";
                break;
            }               
        }

        if(tempCom!="" && tempCom.length()>commonStr.length()){
            commonStr=tempCom;  
        }                       
    }   

    return commonStr;
}
```

**Note:** Longest Common Substring problem is different from Longest Common [Subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) problem since unlike substrings, subsequences are not required to occupy consecutive positions within the original sequences.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) and has been the subject of some research (also see the [longest common subsequence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)). You should read about the problem and then implement the appropriate algorithm.

Implementing the full algorithm is something I don't have time for, but I have found [this blog post](https://karussell.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/longest-common-substring-algorithm-in-java/) which has an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case you can start comparing the substrings, incrementing the length of substring in each pass